# How can I access database from spring application context XML?

Tags: java, spring, repository, dao

I have some beans that need to use another bean that must be loaded from database. I use Hibernate and have a DAO annotated with @Repository.

I managed to do it defining the bean as singleton and use the DAO as it's factory in the XML but since the Repositories are not explicit in the XML it feels dirty to me.

Is there <strike>a more elegant</strike> an easier to understand solution?

Here is an extract of application-context-beans.xml:

```
<bean id="myBean"
        class="myBeanClass">
    <property name="defaultMyValue">
        <bean factory-bean="myValueDAO" factory-method="getEntity">
            <constructor-arg value="0" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

myValueDAO is not defined on an XML but a class anotated with @Repository

This code works but I don't like it and the Spring IDE Eclipse feature don't like it either ;-)

Comment: Added dummy code as @malejpavouk asked

Comment: That table of 'values' has two columns (id, name) and should not change and definitely they will not change at runtime but someone else decided they have to be defined on a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sort of an aesthetic judgement about how much you want to do in Java and how much in XML, considering factors like who's going to maintain this in the future and what kind of changes they're likely to make.

As for me, I don't like putting plain old domain objects directly in the context configuration unless it's something like a `util:properties` that contains data my other beans need to initialize themselves. If using the solution you have feels too much like deep black magic to you, then write your own `FactoryBean` that takes an instance of the DAO (which can even be autowired if you like) and returns an instance of `myBeanClass`.

Comment: It's the best solution to me by now, creating a bean that wraps the DAO for this case so the 'factory' is defined on the XML.

Comment: '_factors_ _like_ _who's_ _going_ _to_ _maintain_ _this_ _in_ _the_ _future_' I don't know who will mantain this. If I knew I will maintain it I would not be worried about getting a solution that is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It may only make sense if your bean is an immutable Hibernate object that does not contain dependent persisted beans/collections. Otherwise you may trap into problems with different sessions and lazy-loading exceptions. Could you explain in detail why you use such a doubtful from the architectural perspective approach?

Comment: Since you don't have reputation to comment and you are trying to help me I will not vote negative this 'answer' that do not answer ;-) I will not explain why I did the things that way, I am asking how should I do them.